# Performance differences when looping over arrays of structs

Tags: arrays, julia

I have recently started using Julia to speed up some code previously written in Python. I only have prior experience with Python, so this is my first time caring about performance and I have found some strange behavior when looping over an array of structs. I am defining a new struct Gaussian, which represent a 2d Gaussian function and a function intensity() which calculates the amplitude of the function at a given position:

```
struct Gaussian{T<:Float32}
    x0::T
    y0::T
    A::T
    a::T
    b::T
    c::T
end

function intensity(
    model::Gaussian,
    x::Float32,
    y::Float32
    )
    gaussian_value::Float32 = model.A*exp(
        -( 
            model.a * (x - model.x0)^2 +
            2 * model.b * (x - model.x0) * (y - model.y0) +
            model.c * (y - model.y0)^2
        )
    )
    return gaussian_value
end
```

Then, I make an array of 2000 random instances of Gaussian:

```
function build_array()
    length = 2000
    random_pos = [rand(Float32, (1, 2)) for i in 1:length]
    random_A = rand(Float32, (length, 1))
    random_a = rand(Float32, (length, 1))
    random_b = rand(Float32, (length, 1))
    random_c = rand(Float32, (length, 1));

    gaussians::Array{Gaussian} = []

    for (pos, A, a, b, c) in zip(
        random_pos,
        random_A,
        random_a,
        random_b,
        random_c
        )
        new_gaussian = Gaussian(pos..., A, a, b, c)
        push!(gaussians, new_gaussian)
    end
    
    return gaussians
end

gaussians = build_array()
```

When I benchmark a single call to the intensity() function, it takes ~100 ns with 1 allocation (makes sense). I would expect that looping over the array of Gaussians should then take 2000*100 ns = 200 us. However, it actually takes about twice as long:

```
function total_intensity1(gaussian_list::Array{Gaussian})
    total = sum(intensity.(gaussian_list, Float32(0.75), Float32(0.11)))
end

function total_intensity2(gaussian_list::Array{Gaussian})
    total::Float32 = 0.
    for gaussian in gaussian_list
        total += intensity(gaussian, Float32(0.75), Float32(0.11))
    end
    return total 
end

@btime sum(intensity.(gaussians, Float32(0.75), Float32(0.11)))
@btime begin
    total::Float32 = 0.
    for gauss in gaussians
        total += intensity(gauss, Float32(0.75), Float32(0.11))
    end
    total
end
@btime total_intensity1(gaussians)
@btime total_intensity2(gaussians)
```

```
  397.700 μs (16004 allocations: 258.02 KiB)
  285.800 μs (8980 allocations: 234.06 KiB)
  396.100 μs (16002 allocations: 257.95 KiB)
  396.700 μs (16001 allocations: 250.02 KiB)
```

The number of allocations is also much larger than I would expect and there is a difference between the second and fourth method even though the code is pretty much the same. My questions:

1. Where do these differences come from?
2. How can I improve the performance of the code?

EDIT:
For reference, I ended up changing my code to the following:

```
struct Gaussian
    x0::Float32
    y0::Float32
    A::Float32
    a::Float32
    b::Float32
    c::Float32
end

function build_array()
    N = 2000
    random_pos = [rand(Float32, (1, 2)) for i in 1:N]
    random_A = rand(Float32, N)
    random_a = rand(Float32, N)
    random_b = rand(Float32, N)
    random_c = rand(Float32, N);

    gaussians = Gaussian[]

    for (pos, A, a, b, c) in zip(
        random_pos,
        random_A,
        random_a,
        random_b,
        random_c
        )
        new_gaussian = Gaussian(pos..., A, a, b, c)
        push!(gaussians, new_gaussian)
    end
    
    return gaussians
end

gaussians = build_array()

function intensity(
    model::Gaussian,
    x,
    y
    )
    (;x0, y0, A, a, b, c) = model
    A*exp(-(a * (x - x0)^2 + 2 * b * (x - x0) * (y - y0) + c * (y - y0)^2))
end

function total_intensity(gaussian_list::Vector{<:Gaussian})
    total = sum(g->intensity(g, Float32(0.75), Float32(0.11)), gaussian_list)
end

@btime total_intensity($gaussians)
```

Which runs much faster:

```
10.900 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Thank you to Nils Gudat and DNF for their suggestions!

Comment: Not that it's super important, I guess, but if you care about performance, `build_array` can be a one-liner that makes no unnecessary allocations. The key is to avoid creating intermediate arrays, like `random_pos`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR version: `Vector{Gaussian}` should be `Vector{Gaussian{Float32}}`.

Your struct definition `Gaussian{T<:Float32}` is somewhat nonsensical. `Float32` cannot have any subtypes, so `T` can *only* be a `Float32`. Therefore, either remove the restriction, replace it with something else (e.g. `Real`), or just take away the type parameter entirely.

This is bad:

```
gaussians::Array{Gaussian} = []
```

It creates a `Vector{Any}` which it then converts to a `Vector{Gaussian}`. Worse, `Vector{Gaussian}` is *not* a `Vector{Gaussian{Float32}}`. So either remove the whole type parameter, or make sure to use it. So,

```
# good:
gaussians = Vector{Gaussian{Float32}}()
gaussians = Gaussian{Float32}[] # same as above

# bad
gaussians = Vector{Gaussian}()
# very bad, don't use this style, put types on the right hand side when constructing.
gaussians::Vector{Gaussian} = []
```

Same here, bad style

```
total::Float32 = 0.
```

Do this instead

```
total = Float32(0.0)
# or use Float32 literal
total = 0.0f0
# or the generic way
total = zero(Float32)
```

In dynamic languages, types belong to *values*, not to variables.

BTW, you'll have to modify some of your function definitions:

```
total_intensity1(gaussian_list::Array{Gaussian})
```

should be

```
total_intensity1(gaussian_list::Array{<:Gaussian})
```

There's more, but this is a start.

**Edit:** OK, a few more things:

1. `rand(Float32, (length, 1))`
   `length` is a super important function in Base, so it's normally good not to shadow it like this. And, make vectors instead of matrices:

   `rand(Float32, (N, 1)) # this is an Nx1 matrix`

   `rand(Float32, N) # this is a length-N vector`
2. `push!(gaussians, new_gaussian)`
   This iteratively resizes the vector over and over. When you know the size of the vector as in your case, it is better to pre-allocate:

   `gaussians = Vector{Gaussian{Float32}}(undef, 2000)`
3. You can avoid an unnecessary allocation here:

   `total = sum(intensity.(gaussian_list, Float32(0.75), Float32(0.11)))`
   like this:

   `total = sum(g->intensity(g, 0.75f0, 0.11f0), gaussian_list)`

Explanation: `sum(f.(x))` first creates the array `f.(x)`, then sums it, while `sum(f, x)` just applies `f` to each element before adding it to the sum.

Here's an implementation with benchmarks:

```
struct Gaussian{T<:Real}
    x0::T
    y0::T
    A::T
    a::T
    b::T
    c::T
end
Gaussian(x::Real...) = Gaussian(promote(x...)...)

function intensity(model::Gaussian, x::Real, y::Real)
    val = model.A * exp(
        -( 
            model.a * (x - model.x0)^2 +
            2 * model.b * (x - model.x0) * (y - model.y0) +
            model.c * (y - model.y0)^2
        )
    )
    return val
end

function build_array(N=2000)
    return [Gaussian(ntuple(_->rand(Float32), 6)...) for _ in 1:N]
end
```

Benchmarks (remember to interpolate variables, and avoid global scope):

```
julia> gaussians = build_array(2000);

julia> @btime sum(intensity.($gaussians, Float32(0.75), Float32(0.11)))
  14.600 μs (1 allocation: 7.94 KiB)
947.5305f0

julia> @btime sum(g->intensity(g, 0.75f0, 0.11f0), $gaussians)
  12.600 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
947.5309f0
```

There's a slight difference in the final sums, since sum of vector uses a numerically superior method called pairwise summation.

Final bonus: Try Tullio.jl, which also uses multithreading. It doesn't make any difference for 2000 elements, but it does for larger arrays (using 12 threads here):

```
julia> using Tullio, LoopVectorization

julia> gaussians = build_array(200_000);

julia> @btime sum(g->intensity(g, 0.75f0, 0.11f0), $gaussians)
  1.228 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
92722.7f0

julia> @btime @tullio s := intensity($gaussians[i], 0.75f0, 0.11f0)
  330.100 μs (197 allocations: 11.53 KiB)
92722.79f0
```

Comment: When you say that `gaussians::Vector{Gaussian} = []` is bad, do you mean because you're creating an array containing abstract Gaussian types? Just like how it says to avoid containers with abstract types in the [Performance Tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#man-performance-abstract-container)?

Comment: Yes, but also the use of the notation `x::A = b` is not good. One should use `x = A(b)` instead, especially in cases like this where it leads to unnecessary operations.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time to figure this one out in detail unfortunately, but the first thing I'd say is check whether this is a benchmarking artifact - `gaussians` is a global variable which should be interpolated into the benchmark using `$`.

As to your function, the type annotations are not doing anything for performance here, and will make your function less composable (e.g. you won't be able to autodiff through it give you're restricting everything to `Float32`).

Here's how I would write it:

```
function intensity(m, x, y)
    (; x₀, y₀, A, a, b, c) = m # destructuring input
    A * exp( -(a * (x - x₀)^2 + 2b * (x - x₀) * (y - y₀) + c * (y - y₀)^2 ) )
end
```

With that I'm getting:

```
  231.100 μs (12001 allocations: 195.44 KiB)
  231.500 μs (12001 allocations: 195.44 KiB)
  229.200 μs (12000 allocations: 187.50 KiB)
  229.300 μs (12000 allocations: 187.50 KiB)
```

which is about 100μs faster than your original version on my machine.